# how can I resolve HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error iis windows server 2019?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, plesk, windows-server, windows-server-2019

Some of my websites return an error C when I restart the server website works fine but after some time(1 day, 2 days, or week) it returns this error again. please help me resolve this error because I don't want to restart the server every time.
I am using IIS and Windows server 2019 and plesk panel.

Comment: 500.0 indicates unhandled exceptions in your web apps in general. So you should learn how to configure global exception handlers and use that to capture the actual errors.

Comment: I have tried some of the solutions available on internet after that now error has been modified Please view the bellow link containing screenshots for error and help me resolving this issue.
https://ibb.co/kGStJ0d